# "Scholar" vs. "scientist"

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences, nouns

I mainly associate *scholar* with *scholarship*. But what's its etymological origin? On scientific websites both *scholar* and *scientist* seem to be used with the same meaning; A graduate working actively on a scientific topic. Is it a AE/BE thing or does scholar imply the graduate is doing a phd/postdoctoral degree or gets financial aid (scholarship).

Also, how do these terms relate to *researcher*? You don't need an academic degree to be a researcher, e.g. a journalist does research before writing an article. But in my opinion *researcher* also often implies someone has an academic degree. Is this right?

Comment: You have a lot of questions here. Do you think you can pare them down to get better answers?

Comment: @simchona im asking for correct context of scholar/scientist/researcher as they are used in a synonymous way imo. Where are there *a lot* of questions? Its one, the rest are my assumptions and hints that might play a role and may be considered when writing a answer...

Comment: You ask for the etymology of "scholar", what "scientist" implies, how "scientist" and "scholar" and "researcher" relate, and what a "researcher" is.

Comment: @simchona Of course? As all these questions contribute to the differentiation of these terms as thursagen answer shows.It makes only sense TO ME to bundle these sub-nearly-questions in one complete question instead of making 5 separate ones probably yielding no votes and answers as uninteresting.Otherwise you say its ok to make for every etymological origin/word meaning question a thread here instead of simply looking it up in a dictionary?Im ONLY asking on usage in context, necessarily imho the answer on this single question will regard all my sub questions and more to yield the best answer.

Comment: The core distinction is that a scientist's scientific knowledge is based on experimentation whereas a scholar's knowledge is based on the study of non-experimental evidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["Scientist"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scientist) is used when referring specifically to a person who is an expert in a science, especially physical or natural sciences.

["Scholar"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scholar) is more broad, and can be used generally for anyone who has profound knowledge of a particular subject.

*"Scholar" isn't used for sciences* (chemistry, geography), but can be used for History, Language, etc. Examples of this are:

> Geography scholar?/Wrong.
>   Language scholar - Yes.
>   Psychology scholar - Wrong.(Psychology is a science)
>   Greek scholar - Correct.

Thus, "scholar" is only used for someone who is an expert at a particular subject, when the subject is not a science.

An additional meaning of ["scholar" is:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scholar)

> a student who has been awarded a scholarship.

Thus, yes, "scholar" can also be used when referring to students who have received scholarships, as you asked.

Your second question below:

A "researcher" implies someone who is doing scientific research specifically as a vocation e.g. I am a researcher at Harvard University.  If someone like a journalist was just doing research for an article, he wouldn't be referred to as a researcher, but rather as "A journalist researching".

A "researcher" could be a scientist, or a scholar. A Biblical scholar could be a researcher at a seminary. A chemist could be a researcher at a pharmacist. But when referring to the person, it doesn't matter if he/she is a scientist or a scholar, just use "researcher".

Comment: Someone please comment on why this was down-voted?

Comment: Maybe someone disagreed with your originally cursory definitions? (It wasn't me)

Comment: Cursory definitions? as in what?

Comment: Your first three lines have no references, and maybe somebody disagreed with them because of that. I'm still saying it wasn't me; I haven't voted on this question.

Comment: +1 from me. Maybe someone doenst agree on what topic is a science? But your answer makes sense to me, scholar more broad is correct as far as i looked up the meanings in dictionary...So you would call a *researcher* someone currently working in industry/university AS a scientist/scholar (Activitiy to earn your money with a academic degree)? Scientist/Scholar (depending on topic) his vocation based on education? Is this a correct sum up? Activity vs. Education? I asked this as i read the terms in many similar contexts, so maybe there is no clearcut accordance in usage, but a synonymous

Comment: Correct about the Scientist/Scholar meaning. Researcher is wroking in an industry/university *researching* as his job, and he can be either a scientist/scholar.

Comment: Perhaps someone thinks "geography scholar", "chemistry scholar", etc. are OK?

Comment: 'Scholar' certainly is used for someone outside of the humanities (check the definition you linked to). 'Scholar' standing by itself does have the connotation of reading quite a bit, which is not the scientist's primary source of knowledge. See the following [Google ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=scholar+in+psychology%2Cscholar+in+history%2C+scholar+of+psychology%2Cscholar+of+history&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) comparing 'history' and 'psychology'. 'History' wins, but 'psychology' actually has a showing (see examples there to confirm).

Comment: I broadly agree with the answer but you can refer to a scientist as a scholar.

Comment: I am impressed with the large number of articles on hydroquinone chemistry that Google Scholar erroneously includes in their "non-science" database: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=hydroquinones&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C28&as_sdtp= Baryon oscillation also rates a disturbingly high number of scholarly refs, despite being primarily of interest to astronomers and physicists: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,28&q=baryon+oscillation

Comment: Researcher is also used for someone working in TV production in quite a general role; for a fact-checker in publishing etc; for someone who works for a writer in a junior capacity doing menial research work; etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Scholar*: from the Ancient Greek *scoulari*; noun for "skeptic".